# remove new line spaces from json file and reading it in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, newline, spaces

```
{"country":"India","city":"Chennai","lat":13.0827,"lon":80.2707,"isp":"Facebook, Inc.","query":"157.240.23.19"}
{"country":"India","city":"Mumbai","lat":19.076,"lon":72.8777,"isp":"Facebook, Inc.","query":"31.13.79.18"}
{"country":"India","city":"Bhadohi","lat":25.3953,"lon":82.5703,"isp":"Railtel Enterprise Limited","query":"122.252.234.36"}
{"country":"India","city":"Mumbai","lat":19.076,"lon":72.8777,"isp":"Google LLC","query":"172.217.160.195"}
{"country":"India","city":"Gurugram","lat":28.4498,"lon":77.0761,"isp":"RailTel Corporation of India Ltd.","query":"122.252.245.12"}
{"country":"India","city":"Bhadohi","lat":25.3953,"lon":82.5703,"isp":"Railtel Enterprise Limited","query":"122.252.234.36"}
{"country":"India","city":"Chennai","lat":13.0827,"lon":80.2707,"isp":"Google LLC","query":"172.217.163.195"}
```

This is a sample of my JSON file. I want to load it into a pandas dataframe.

Method I tried was `data = pd.read_json("test.json",lines = True).`

but I am getting this error Unexpected character found when decoding array value (2)
I think I am having new line characters and extra spaces. How should I remove them and load it???

Answer (score 0):

Your sample json file is incorrect, If you are using lines=True, each object should be in new line, and not in single line.

```
{"country":"India","city":"Chennai","lat":13.0827,"lon":80.2707,"isp":"Facebook, Inc.","query":"157.240.23.19"}
{"country":"India","city":"Mumbai","lat":19.076,"lon":72.8777,"isp":"Facebook, Inc.","query":"31.13.79.18"}
{"country":"India","city":"Bhadohi","lat":25.3953,"lon":82.5703,"isp":"Railtel Enterprise Limited","query":"122.252.234.36"}
{"country":"India","city":"Mumbai","lat":19.076,"lon":72.8777,"isp":"Google LLC","query":"172.217.160.195"}
{"country":"India","city":"Gurugram","lat":28.4498,"lon":77.0761,"isp":"RailTel Corporation of India Ltd.","query":"122.252.245.12"}
{"country":"India","city":"Bhadohi","lat":25.3953,"lon":82.5703,"isp":"Railtel Enterprise Limited","query":"122.252.234.36"}
{"country":"India","city":"Chennai","lat":13.0827,"lon":80.2707,"isp":"Google LLC","query":"172.217.163.195"}
```

Comment: tried it with lines =  True as well as without it still getting the same error  . I actually referred this link https://riptutorial.com/pandas/example/30303/read-json-from-file

Comment: @KunalVerma you need to have json object in new lines, I have edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: These objects are in new line only . I think there are new line characters or spaces thats why I am getting errors